# Collective noun + sing./pl. verb

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, grammatical-number

```
If one is a tooth and a whole set are teeth,
Why shouldn't the plural of booth be called beeth?
```

Why is the verb in the clause ***a whole set are teeth*** plural? Doesn't [Aspinea's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/128477/does-the-verb-after-set-of-agree-with-set-or-the-plural-noun-that-follows) apply here, that it should be singular [a whole set is teeth]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a **linguistic humor** and so, not *all grammar rules shall apply.* That's what I think. To throw a pun a little flexibility in syntax is allowed. That's why, maybe, this is like that.

I agree that *a whole set is teeth* makes the sentence more grammatical but on the other hand, if you think - *If [one is tooth] and a [whole set] (now becoming plural as there are several toothS! [are teeth].* may make a sense though it's silly!

Another such with no strict rule is..

> The masculine pronouns are he, his and him, but imagine the feminine she, shis, and shim!

Comment: Not only is it humour but I think it's intended to be poetry, and poets also have a license to bend the rules.